# Redirect user depending on screen height and weight

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I'm trying to make script to redirect user on mobile version on site, but different version for iPhone 3, 4 and iPhone 5. I use this code it works for iPhone 3,4 and computer but it doesn't work for iPhone 5. When I open my page with iPhone 5 script redirects me to iPhone 3, 4 page. Can somebody please help me?

```
<head>
<script>
if ( (screen.width = 320) && (screen.height = 480) ) { 
window.location = 'iphone4.html';
}
if ( (screen.width = 320) && (screen.height = 568) ) { 
window.location = 'iphone5.html';
} 
if ( (screen.width > 320) && (screen.height > 568) ) { 
window.location = 'comp.html';
} 
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: USE === not = for comparisons PLEASE

Comment: Value of `window.location` property you assigning should be whole URL (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare stuff using

```
if(variable == value)
```

Not using

```
if(variable = value)
```

So please edit your code, it will work!

First clause compares the two values and gives out a BOOLEAN result; either true or false. Whereas the second clause alters the value of the variable, and gives it a new value that is provided in the right side of the equal sign.

So your code would be more like this one:

```
if (screen.width == 320 && screen.height == 480) { // comparison
  window.location = 'iphone4.html'; // altering value
}
if (screen.width == 320 && screen.height == 568) { // comparison
  window.location = 'iphone5.html'; // altering value
} 
if (screen.width > 320 && screen.height > 568) { // comparison
  window.location = 'comp.html'; // altering value
}
```

Comment: `==` or `===`. `==` will do type coercion, the rules of which are complex. `===` won't, so `"1" == 1` is true but `"1" === 1` is false.

Comment: But wouldn't the code I provided be true? As I am having `320` as int not a string..:)

Comment: Yes, it's just you open saying you use `==`, and I was just pointing out there is a second option (`===`). (Side note: The 320 above is not an int, it's a `Number`. JavaScript doesn't have `int`.)